# Custom e-commerce tracking code for Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, tracking

Which file do I need to add custom e-commerce tracking code to in Magento?

Knowing that will give me a good start because Magento is huge and do not know where to start.

Once I know the correct file I need to add javascript into the checkout completed page, the javascript will be interjected with some values

- items bought
- total cost
- cost / item
- etc

The javascript I have and can handle just fine, its the Magento bit I am struggling with;

1. Where should I add this javascript?
2. Once I find this file can I easily output the transactions details the javascript tracker requires.

Note that the javascript is for https://www.gosquared.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add this script in `success.phtml` from checkout/success.phtml in this file you got `$order` object and you get all information from this object like your transaction id,product information just like ex.

```
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$transactionid=$this->getOrderId()



foreach ($order->getItemsCollection() as $item) 
    {
        $item->getData();
        $proidcol[]=$item->getData('product_id');
        $pronamecol[]=$item->getData('name');
        $proqtycol[]=$item->getData('qty_ordered');
        $productpricecol[]=$item->getPrice();
    }
```

in this `$pronamecol` you can get all product name array from order and then implement this in java-script code using for loop ,,I think you can easily do that

Answer (score 0):

1 To add the javascript to the success page, you can use this in your layout local.xml file:

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/path/to/file.js</name></action>
    </reference>
<checkout_onepage_success>
```

Instead of head, you could also use before_body_end (so the javascript gets added at the bottom of the page).

2 Can't tell for you at the moment, what information does your javascript need? Do you need to add information to it manually?

Comment: Mike, this is what I need to implement https://www.gosquared.com/developer/tracker/ecommerce/

Comment: I've seen things like those before, I'd say just try it on your local machine first. Add the javascript to your success page and see if you get any results. Otherwise you'll probably have to add custom code to the success template (or a child template) and get the information required for that javascript